# ASP.NET CORE 6 MVC Controller no deserializa JSON muy largo

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola tengo un Controlador que recibe un objeto desde Javascript, cuando el objeto es pequeño funciona bien pero cuando es grande siempre me regresa null. Existe forma de incrementar la longuitud del JSON que puede recibir el controlador?

busque y encontre que se tiene que poner una variable en el web.config pero yo no tengo web.config (tambien ya lo agregue manualmente y no funciona)

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te arroja? Porque si es null llega al controller y te arroja null? no "bindea a datos"? porque hay varios configuraciones que pueden ser. ¿Estas utlizando kestrel para probar en tu maquina de desarrollo o IIS Express? ¿Tu objeto que intentas bindear es "complejo" o es decir tiene objetos anidados? Si puedes completar con esto tu pregunta te podriamos ayudar mas especificamente.

Comment: Aclaracion, la configuracion que estas utilizando con [jsonSerialization maxJsonLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength?view=netframework-4.8.1) solo funciona para NET Framework y tu estas utilizando .NET Core 6

Comment: Si te devuelve "null" es que no logra realizar el binding al modelo, porque o esta el JSON mal armado, o falta algun dato requerido del modelo. Dale una mirada al ModelState.IsValid dentro del controller si lo que envias es Valido o no. POrque si no te arroja ninguna Excepcion es mas bien este tipo de inconveniente. Esperamos que completes tu pregunta con estos "tips" para poder ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo pude resolver poniendo esto y si era porque el JSON que enviaba al controlador era muy largo. Espero que le sirva a alguien m+as y muchas gracias a los que me responieron

```
builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
    options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    options.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
```